# How can I get my TextBlock to move across the screen at a steady pace no matter the length of its text?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm trying to create some scrolling text (a marquee) in a desktop application. I originally tried to use timer ticks but as the time between ticks can be unreliable this resulted in jerky animation. I'm now trying to use WPF native animations instead.

I have a `TextBlock` placed inside a `Canvas`. I can scroll the text easily with a standard `DoubleAnimation`.

```
var MyAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
{
    From = this.ActualWidth,
    To = -MyTextBlock.ActualWidth,
    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15000))
};

MyTextBlock.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, MyAnimation);
```

This causes my default textblock to scroll across the screen at a readable speed  until it disappears.

My problem is that the length of the text inside the textblock will periodically change. This causes an issue as smaller text now goes across the screen very slowly but large text flies past. This is because the duration is unchanged.

I will know the width in pixels of both the application and the textblock at runtime. I tried to calculate some ratio between the two that would let me work out the appropriate duration but it's hopelessly inaccurate.

```
var span = Convert.ToInt32((((double)textwidth / appwidth) * 1000) * 10);
...
Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(span))
```

**Is there a recommended way to get textblock to move across the screen at a steady pace no matter the length of the text?**

Here is a visual example of what I mean.
Observe what it looks like when the text length is increased but the duration is left the same. The longer text moves faster.
[image]

This is what it looks like when I've manually adjusted the duration to a longer period.
[image]

I can't figure out how you'd calculate the duration automatically based on the width of the app and the length of the text.

(Ignore the jerky scrolling, it's a 15fps GIF, it's actually buttery smooth)

Comment: are you familiar with google? I did a google search and it came up with so many examples on how to do this for instance [Hot to add Scrolling/Moving text in TextBlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513419/how-to-add-scrolling-moving-text-in-textblock-in-xaml)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add scrolling/moving text in textblock in xaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30513419/how-to-add-scrolling-moving-text-in-textblock-in-xaml)

Comment: @MethodMan Don't be so patronising. The examples you're referring to are fine if the text is static and you've previously worked out an appropriate duration for said text. If the text changes then it's no good having the same duration as before as the text will now scroll faster/slower than before....

Comment: @d.moncada Not a duplicate. I've already shown I know how to move static text with a static duration, this doesn't work if the text changes. The answer you linked uses timers which are not useful...

Comment: "Is there a recommended way to get textblock to move across the screen at a steady pace no matter the length of the text?". No, there is no such thing as a common "steady pace". You will have to calculate and define your own pace.

Comment: @mm8 I get that, and defining your own pace is easy when the length of the text never changes. I've added additional clarification in the hopes that people are simply misunderstanding what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula that's required is:

> time = distance / speed

The code I showed becomes:

```
double speed = 200.0;

var MyAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
{
    From = this.ActualWidth,
    To = -MyTextBlock.ActualWidth,
    Duration = new Duration(
                     TimeSpan.FromSeconds(
                       Math.Abs(
                         this.ActualWidth - MyTextBlock.ActualWidth) / speed))
};

MyTextBlock.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, MyAnimation);
```

Now the blocks move across the screen at the same pace no matter the width.

Answer (score 1):

You want the duration to be based on `textWidth + appWidth`, not `textWidth / appWidth` . The total distance that the marquee travels is the screen width plus the width of the text block, not a ratio of the two.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Specifically you need `(textwidth + appwidth) / speed', where `speed` is a `double` representing pixels per second.